# How can I format my own Page Numbers?

Tags: microsoft-word

I like my page numbers to be on the upper right like "Bold Numbers 3" below, but I prefer no bold and a different font and size. How can I format myself and add my creation to Page Number, so that I don't have to re-create it every time?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the page number based on "Bold Numbers 3", remove bold and use a different font and size.

[image]

Then you can select the page number and click Page Number > Top of Page > Save Selection as Page Number(Top):

[image]

Give it a name and save it:

[image]

You will get a new custom Page Number style:

[image]